# How to Port Qt 4.8 to Android Platform

Tags: android, qt, ubuntu, qt4

I am trying to port Calligra to Android.But I am really confused about the Qt part-what to do with that.I am somehow comfortable with the dependencies that needs to be identified to port calligra on Android but I am not finding any way what needs to be done to port Qt on Android which is required before porting Calligra.
Can someone help me out on this or if someone has any other idea on how shall I proceed to port Calligra which I have built on Ubuntu to Android Platform.

Can someone help me in guiding how to port Qt on Android.I know its a tricky thing but if someone has worked previously on this.

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has already been done: look for necessitas. You're provided both compiled binaries and the sources.

Comment: https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/mobile/necessitas       ----Are you talking about this?

Comment: ok thanks Luca.One last question-Will it require Ministro.apk to do this or it can be done even without this apk also.

Comment: You have to provide the libraries either with Ministro or with your package.

Comment: it looks the project is dead on KDE ... the link is not working as stated in `Go on the necessitas project home page, find and download the last stable binary version: (get it from here: http://necessitas.kde.org/necessitas/necessitas_sdk_installer.php)`

Comment: actually, it looks Qt5 has necessitas in it. https://wiki.qt.io/Necessitas

Comment: The official Qt project has been officially ported to both iOS and Android years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check with Mek of the Calligra team over on the #Calligra IRC channel on Freenode, who has been working on Calligra for Android over the last couple of months. Since it seems you two are working on the same thing and he's considerably ahead of you, you might want to help him rather than do double-work :)

most recent blog entry as of writing time: http://blogs.kde.org/node/4553